# How do I put a button to refresh my datasource in my telerik kendo mobile app?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, refresh

I am trying to create a refresh button on the top strip of my app and I cannot find any good info on how to do it without doing the "pull-to-refresh" way. Here is an example app of how I am doing here: http://jsbin.com/naxolu/3/edit
Here is some sample code:

HTML

```
<div data-role="view" id="home" data-title="Headlines" data-model="viewModel">
    <ul id ="homeList" data-role="listview" data-style="inset" class="newslist" data-template="storyList-template" 
        data-bind="source: newsItems, 
                   events: { 
                       click: selectHeadline}">
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="view" id="crime" data-title="Headlines" data-model="viewModel">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" class="newslist" data-template="storyList-template" data-bind="source: newsItems, events: { click: selectHeadline }"></ul>
</div>

  <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="storyList-template">
        <a href="\\#">
            <div class="storyImg" id="#: id #" style=" background-image: url( #:thumbnail# ); margin-top: 0;">
            </div>
            <div class="blackBox">
                <div class="storyTitle">#: trunc_title #</div>
                <div class="timeStamp">#: list_date #</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </script>
```

JS

```
var data = {
        "AllArticles": [{ "id": 1,"trunc_title": "Title for 1","content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id placerat nisl. In finibus scelerisque tempor. Nunc eleifend quam risus, lacinia fermentum dui tincidunt gravida. </p>", "list_date": "2015-10-31 11:08:00","thumbnail": "http://placehold.it/640x360"},{"id": 2,"trunc_title": "Title for 2","content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id placerat nisl. In finibus scelerisque tempor. Nunc eleifend quam risus, lacinia fermentum dui tincidunt gravida. </p>","list_date": "2015-10-31 11:08:00", "thumbnail": "http://placehold.it/640x360" }, { "id": 3, "trunc_title": "Title for 3", "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id placerat nisl. In finibus scelerisque tempor. Nunc eleifend quam risus, lacinia fermentum dui tincidunt gravida. </p>","list_date": "2015-10-31 11:08:00","thumbnail": "http://placehold.it/640x360"},{ "id": 4,"trunc_title": "Title for 1","content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id placerat nisl. In finibus scelerisque tempor. Nunc eleifend quam risus, lacinia fermentum dui tincidunt gravida. </p>", "list_date": "2015-10-31 11:08:00","thumbnail": "http://placehold.it/640x360"},{"id": 5,"trunc_title": "Title for 2","content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id placerat nisl. In finibus scelerisque tempor. Nunc eleifend quam risus, lacinia fermentum dui tincidunt gravida. </p>","list_date": "2015-10-31 11:08:00", "thumbnail": "http://placehold.it/640x360" }, { "id": 6, "trunc_title": "Title for 3", "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id placerat nisl. In finibus scelerisque tempor. Nunc eleifend quam risus, lacinia fermentum dui tincidunt gravida. </p>","list_date": "2015-10-31 11:08:00","thumbnail": "http://placehold.it/640x360"}]
    };

/*

I am pulling it from an external site like this:

viewModel[i] = new kendo.observable({
            newsItems: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: serviceURL,
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "posts"
                }
            })
            }
        });


*/
var viewModel = new kendo.observable({
  newsItems: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: data.AllArticles
  }),
  selectedStory: {},
  selectHeadline: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var story = e.dataItem;
    story.dateString = story.date.toLocaleDateString();
    viewModel.set("selectedStory", story);
    app.navigate("#detailsPage");
  }
});

var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {skin: 'flat'});
```

I am pulling my data from another site. I just created mock data so that you can see the example. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a button, say to the header or some such, that calls a function on your viewmodel.  If the viewmodel is bound to a remote json source, then simply calling .read() on your dataSource would cause it to re-fetch the data.  If you are manually fetching the data, you would need to re-fetch the data manually, and then call .read() on your dataSource.

Here is a quick sample that uses a method to add an item to the source (to fake like there is a new data item), and then calls read on the dataSource.

http://jsbin.com/kuyoxu/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: This is how I did it. I can't see if it works yet because the y havent posted a new article yet but Im not getting any error messasges $("#refresh").on("click", function() {
        console.log("working");
            viewModel.neswItems.read();
    });